# Unexpected quicksort behaviour in R

Tags: r, quicksort, montecarlo

So I made a Monte Carlo Quicksort algorithm in R what uses **`sample`** function to determine the position of the new pivot at each iteration. 
My quicksort function looks like this:

```
quickSort=function(arr, left, right) {
  i = left
  j = right
  pivot = arr[sample(left:right, size=1)]
  while (i <= j) {
    while (arr[i] < pivot)
      i=i+1
    while (arr[j] > pivot)
      j=j-1
    if (i <= j) {
      tmp = arr[i]
      arr[i] <<- arr[j]
      arr[j] <<- tmp
      i=i+1
      j=j-1
    }
  }
  if (left < j)
    quickSort(arr, left, j)
  if(i < right)
    quickSort(arr, i, right)
}
```

For testing purposes I initialize a vector with some random values at each execution of the script: `arr=sample(1:30, size=5)`
This is what my function call looks like, along with the printing of the vector:

```
quickSort(arr, 1, 5)
print(arr)
```

I tested the algorithm in Visual Studio (written in C++ of course) and I get the expected result each time. I'm guessing in R I'm doing something wrong about modifying the vector globally, but I can't figure it out. I'm hoping you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying `arr` globally; you seem to think that therefore the quicksort argument `arr` is modified. In addition your `quicksort` function should return `arr`. And the result of a `quicksort` call should be assigned to `arr`. `arr` will not be modified if you don't that. There is no need to use global assignment `<<-` for `arr`.

Change the `quicksort` function to this:

```
quickSort=function(arr, left, right) {
  i = left
  j = right
  pivot = arr[sample(left:right, size=1)]
  while (i <= j) {
    while (arr[i] < pivot)
      i=i+1
    while (arr[j] > pivot)
      j=j-1
    if (i <= j) {
      tmp = arr[i]
      arr[i] <- arr[j]
      arr[j] <- tmp
      i=i+1
      j=j-1
    }
  }
  if (left < j)
    arr <- quickSort(arr, left, j)
  if(i < right)
    arr <- quickSort(arr, i, right)
  arr
}
```

And now let's try again

```
arr=sample(1:30, size=5) 
arr
#    [1] 27 28  8 15 18
quickSort(arr, 1, 5)
#    [1]  8 15 18 27 28
```

Finally: please use `<-` for assignment. Avoid `=` which only assigns at toplevel.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the use of `<<-`.  First of all, you're updating the variable named `arr` in the parent environment *even if arr wasn't the name of the variable you passed in to quickSort*.  But also, *within* the function arr is still shadowed by the local variable with the same name -- so for instance your recursive calls to quickSort are being passed the vector in the original order, not the vector in the updated order.

Try this instead.  Note that it *returns* the updated vector, rather than trying to update it in the parent environment, but of course you can always call it like `arr <- quickSort(arr, 1, 5)` if you want to update the original variable.

```
quickSort=function(arr, left, right) {
    i = left
    j = right
    pivot = arr[sample(left:right, size=1)]
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
            i=i+1
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j=j-1
        if (i <= j) {
            tmp = arr[i]
            arr[i] <- arr[j]
            arr[j] <- tmp
            i=i+1
            j=j-1
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        arr <- quickSort(arr, left, j)
    if(i < right)
        arr <- quickSort(arr, i, right)
    arr
}
```